# Jquery click function not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let me start this off with I'm working with someone else's code and am still relatively new to jquery/javascript. I am also using classie.js from another file. If any of this code can be improved please let me know - I am still learning.

I would post html but it's rather long. If it's an issue let me know and I will try and get a live version of my site up.

I'm trying to toggle a mobile menu with two different open buttons: sticky-open-button and open-button.

It works fine right up until I go to close the menu element if the target is not the menu element or one of its descendants. Then it will ONLY let openbtn open the menu.

Problem Code:

```
    // close the menu element if the target is not the menu element or one of its descendants..
    content.addEventListener( 'click', function(ev) {
        var target = ev.target;
        if( isOpen && target !== ( openbtn || stickyopenbtn ) ) {
            toggleMenu();
        }

    } );
}
```

All code:

```
(function() {
var bodyEl = document.body,
    content = document.querySelector( '.content-wrap' ),
    stickyopenbtn = document.getElementById( 'sticky-open-button' ),
    closebtn = document.getElementById( 'close-button' ),
    openbtn = document.getElementById( 'open-button' ),
    isOpen = false;

function init() {
    initEvents();
}

function initEvents() {

        openbtn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu );
        stickyopenbtn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu );
        if( closebtn ) {
            closebtn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu );
        }

    // close the menu element if the target is not the menu element or one of its descendants..
    content.addEventListener( 'click', function(ev) {
        var target = ev.target;
        if( isOpen && target !== ( openbtn || stickyopenbtn ) ) {
            toggleMenu();
        }

    } );
}

function toggleMenu() {
    if( isOpen ) {
        classie.remove( bodyEl, 'show-menu' );
    }
    else {
        classie.add( bodyEl, 'show-menu' );
    }
    isOpen = !isOpen;
}



init(); //make onclick talk to menu



})();
```

Comment: The html would be helpful, perhaps you can use http://jsfiddle.net/ to get an example running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your OR condition is wrong as `openbtn || stickyopenbtn` will always return `openbtn` instance so the click of `stickyopenbtn` won't be evaluated.

```
content.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    var target = ev.target;
    if (isOpen && (target !== openbtn && target !== stickyopenbtn)) {
        toggleMenu();
    }
});
```